# Bind_param warning number of variables and parameters don't match

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

When I go to edit anything other than the image and link I get this error "", although it still updates the item and displays it in my list of products as the new updated info. The parameters and variables match and i have counted a number of times, I am starting to think its something else in the code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPL6w.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpiYJ.png)

Here is my code for my edit page:

```
<?php 

require_once 'connect.php';

require_once 'header.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.5/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){


        if( empty($_POST['category']) || empty($_FILES['image']) ||  empty($_POST['productname']) || empty($_POST['price']) || empty($_POST['description']) || empty($_POST['details']) || empty($_POST['spec_1']) || empty($_POST['spec_2']) || empty($_POST['spec_3'])|| empty($_POST['spec_4']) || empty($_POST['spec_5']) || empty($_POST['spec_6']) || empty($_POST['spec_7']) || empty($_POST['spec_8']) || empty($_POST['spec_9']) || empty($_POST['spec_10']) || empty($_POST['info_1']) || empty($_POST['info_2']) || empty($_POST['info_3'])|| empty($_POST['info_4']) || empty($_POST['info_5']) || empty($_POST['info_6']) || empty($_POST['info_7']) || empty($_POST['info_8']) || empty($_POST['info_9']) || empty($_POST['info_10']) || empty($_FILES['link_1'])  )
        {
            echo "Please fillout all required fields"; }


            $category  = $_POST['category'];
            $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $productname = $_POST['productname'];
            $price  = $_POST['price'];
            $description  = $_POST['description'];
            $details = $_POST['details'];
            $spec_1 = $_POST['spec_1'];
            $spec_2 = $_POST['spec_2'];
            $spec_3 = $_POST['spec_3'];
            $spec_4 = $_POST['spec_4'];
            $spec_5 = $_POST['spec_5'];
            $spec_6 = $_POST['spec_6'];
            $spec_7 = $_POST['spec_7'];
            $spec_8 = $_POST['spec_8'];
            $spec_9 = $_POST['spec_9'];
            $spec_10 = $_POST['spec_10'];
            $info_1 = $_POST['info_1'];
            $info_2 = $_POST['info_2'];
            $info_3 = $_POST['info_3'];
            $info_4 = $_POST['info_4'];
            $info_5 = $_POST['info_5'];
            $info_6 = $_POST['info_6'];
            $info_7 = $_POST['info_7'];
            $info_8 = $_POST['info_8'];
            $info_9 = $_POST['info_9'];
            $info_10 = $_POST['info_10'];
            $link_1 = $_FILES['link_1']['name'];


        if ((!($_FILES['image']['name'])) && (!($_FILES['link_1']['name'])) ) {
        $sql = $con->prepare("UPDATE products SET category = ?, productname = ?, price = ?, description = ?, details = ?, spec_1 = ?, spec_2 = ?, 
        spec_3 = ?, spec_4 = ?, spec_5 = ?, spec_6 = ?, spec_7 = ?, spec_8 = ?, spec_9 = ?, spec_10 = ?, info_1 = ?, info_2 = ?,
        info_3 = ?, info_4 = ?, info_5 = ?, info_6 = ?, info_7 = ?, info_8 = ?, info_9 = ?, info_10 = ? WHERE product_id = ?");
        $sql->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssssssssi",$category, $productname, $price, $description, $details, $spec_1, $spec_2, $spec_3, $spec_4, $spec_5, $spec_6, $spec_7, $spec_8, $spec_9, $spec_10, $info_1, $info_2, $info_3, $info_4, $info_5, $info_6, $info_7,$info_8,$info_9,$info_10, $_GET["id"]);
        $sql->execute();


        }else
        $sql = $con->prepare("UPDATE products SET category = ?, image = ?, productname = ?, price = ?, description = ?, details = ?, spec_1 = ?, spec_2 = ?, 
        spec_3 = ?, spec_4 = ?, spec_5 = ?, spec_6 = ?, spec_7 = ?, spec_8 = ?, spec_9 = ?, spec_10 = ?, info_1 = ?, info_2 = ?,
        info_3 = ?, info_4 = ?, info_5 = ?, info_6 = ?, info_7 = ?, info_8 = ?, info_9 = ?, info_10 = ?, link_1 = ? WHERE product_id = ?");
        $sql->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssssssssssi", $category, $image, $productname, $price, $description, $details, $spec_1, $spec_2, $spec_3, $spec_4, $spec_5, $spec_6, $spec_7, $spec_8, $spec_9, $spec_10, $info_1, $info_2, $info_3, $info_4, $info_5, $info_6, $info_7,$info_8,$info_9,$info_10, $link_1, $_GET["id"]);
        if($sql->execute()) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Successfully updated product</div>";
            }else{
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Error: There was an error while updating product info</div>";
                }
        }



        $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;
        $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = ?");
        $sql->bind_param('i', $id);
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->get_result();

        if($result->num_rows < 1){
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
        }
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    ?>



    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="box2">
            <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Modify Product</h3> 
            <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" name="productid">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <input type="text" id="category"  name="category" value="<?php echo $row['category']; ?>" class="form-control"><br>
                <label for="name">Image</label><br><br>
                <span><?php echo '<img src="Images/'. $row['image'], '" />'?></span><br><br>
                <input type="file"  name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>"  class="form-control"><br>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text"  name="productname" id="name" value="<?php echo $row['productname']; ?>" class="form-control"><br>
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input type="text"  name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" class="form-control"><br>
                <label for="description">Description</label> 
                <input type="text"  name="description" id="description"  value="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>" class="form-control"><br>
                <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Modify Product Details</h3><br>
                <label class="heading" for="heading">Product Details</label><br>
                <textarea name="details" id="details" class="form-control ckeditor">
                <?php echo $row['details']; ?>
                </textarea>
                <br>
                <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Modify Specifications</h3><br>
                <label class="heading" for="heading">Heading</label>
                <input type="text" id="spec_1"  name="spec_1" value="<?php echo $row['spec_1']; ?>"class="form-control head_1"><br>
                <label class="information" for="information">Information</label>
                <input type="text" id="info_1"  name="info_1" value="<?php echo $row['info_1']; ?>" class="form-control info_1"><br>
                <input type="text" id="spec_2"  name="spec_2" value="<?php echo $row['spec_2']; ?>"class="form-control head_2"><br>
                <input type="text" id="info_2"  name="info_2" value="<?php echo $row['info_2']; ?>" class="form-control info_2"><br>
                <input type="text" id="spec_3"  name="spec_3" value="<?php echo $row['spec_3']; ?>"class="form-control head_3"><br>
                <input type="text" id="info_3"  name="info_3" value="<?php echo $row['info_3']; ?>" class="form-control info_3"><br>
                <input type="text" id="spec_4"  name="spec_4" value="<?php echo $row['spec_4']; ?>"class="form-control head_4"><br>
                <input type="text" id="info_4"  name="info_4" value="<?php echo $row['info_4']; ?>" class="form-control info_4"><br>
                <input type="text" id="spec_5"  name="spec_5" value="<?php echo $row['spec_5']; ?>"class="form-control head_5"><br>
                <input type="text" id="info_5"  name="info_5" value="<?php echo $row['info_5']; ?>" class="form-control info_5"><br>
                <input type="text" id="spec_6"  name="spec_6" value="<?php echo $row['spec_6']; ?>"class="form-control head_6"><br>
                <input type="text" id="info_6"  name="info_6" value="<?php echo $row['info_6']; ?>" class="form-control info_6"><br>
                <input type="text" id="spec_7"  name="spec_7" value="<?php echo $row['spec_7']; ?>"class="form-control head_7"><br>
                <input type="text" id="info_7"  name="info_7" value="<?php echo $row['info_7']; ?>" class="form-control info_7"><br>
                <input type="text" id="spec_8"  name="spec_8" value="<?php echo $row['spec_8']; ?>"class="form-control head_8"><br>
                <input type="text" id="info_8"  name="info_8" value="<?php echo $row['info_8']; ?>" class="form-control info_8"><br>
                <input type="text" id="spec_9"  name="spec_9" value="<?php echo $row['spec_9']; ?>"class="form-control head_9"><br>
                <input type="text" id="info_9"  name="info_9" value="<?php echo $row['info_9']; ?>" class="form-control info_9"><br>
                <input type="text" id="spec_10"  name="spec_10" value="<?php echo $row['spec_10']; ?>"class="form-control head_10"><br>
                <input type="text" id="info_10"  name="info_10" value="<?php echo $row['info_10']; ?>" class="form-control info_10"><br>
                <h3 class="links"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add New Links</h3><br>
                <label class="links" for="links">Links</label><br><br>
                <span><?php echo $row['link_1']?></span>
                <input type="file"  name="link_1" id="link_1" value="<?php echo $row['link_1']; ?>"  class="form-control"><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success button2" value="Update">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated and apologies I am still new and first attempt at a crud system.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please open `{` on line `61` after `else`? and can you change please `$_GET["id"]` into a variable ? ( so you can clean your data before use that)

Comment: @Simone Rossaini thank you so much for getting back to me and for not ripping me new one. OMG and it was just a left off { hate it when it is something so stupid. So that worked thank you. Changing the $_GET["id"] to $id didn't work though, it just doesn't update, nor echo any messages and no sql error? so not sure why that didnt work, if i leave it as $_GET["id"], it works But thank you so much

Comment: Oh i just got the $id variable to work in place of $_GET["id"], i see what i did wrong. All is working great :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is you didn't open `{` at else line `61` so:

```
}else
$sql = $con->prepare
```

to:

```
}else{
$sql = $con->prepare
```